# How to store multiple values together in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have written a python code, to count the number of queries, and the number of advertisements from log.

For example `(google, 16, 35)` where `google` means query, `16` means query number, `35` means advertisement number.

I thought about defining two dictionaries, one dict is store `query->query_number`, another `query->advertisement`, then join these 2 dicts.

But it seems too complex, is it possible to store `query, query_num, advertisement_num` in a single dictionary?

```
if match[0].strip():
     if not dict.has_key(match[0]):
        dict[match[0]] = 1
     else:
        dict[match[0]] +=1
```

this code is used to caculate the queryNum,but I have to still store the adver_count.How can I do?

I have used class to store the query_num and adver_num.Here is my code.How can I do descend sort by adver_num according?Who can help me?Thanks

```
import re
dict={}
class log:
    def __init__(self,query_num, adver_num):
        self.query_num = query_num
        self.adver_num = adver_num
f = open('result.txt','w')

def sort_by_value(d):
   return sorted(d.items(), lambda x, y: cmp(x[1], y[1]), reverse=True)

for line in open("test.log"):
   count_result = 0
   query_num = 0
   match=re.search('.*qry=(.*?)qid0.*rc=(.*?)discount',line).groups()
   counts=match[1].split('|')
   for count in counts:
      count_result += int(count)
   if match[0].strip():
     if not dict.has_key(match[0]):
        dict[match[0]] = log(1,count_result)
     else:
        query_num = dict[match[0]].query_num+1;
        count_result = dict[match[0]].adver_num+count_result;
        dict[match[0]] = log(query_num,count_result)
     #f.write("%s\t%s\n"%(match[0],count_result))

sort_by_value(dict)

for i in dict.keys():
    f.write("%s\t%s\t%s\n"%(i,dict[i].query_num,dict[i].adver_num))
```

Comment: Sorry, this question is very unclear. Please explain exactly what you want to do.

Comment: the data structure depend on your model : what are the main variables, and the children ones ?  What need to be accessed directly, and what can be looked-up ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use only one dict, `query` as key, and a tuple `(query_num, advertisement_num)` as value.

Code example:

when calculating the queryNum,

```
if match[0].strip():
    if not dict.has_key(match[0]):
        dict[match[0]] = (1,0)
    else:
        qnum, adnum = dict[match[0]]
        dict[match[0]] = (qnum + 1, adnum)
```

Comment: how can I define tuple?Or how can I modify my python code as above?

Comment: @liumilan you can also use classes, for that see my detailed anwser

Comment: @David.Zheng.thanks.I have used it by class as@gen give comments.And the last quesion i would have descending sort by adnum，def sort_by_value(d):
   return [ v for v in sorted(d.values().adver_num)] 。it will report adver_num is not existed.How can I fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can create classes for yourself:

```
class YourClass:
    def __init__(self, query, query_num, adver_num):
        self.query = query
        self.query_num = query_num
        self.adver_num = adver_num
```

Thank you can handle it like:

```
your_dictionary['google'] = YourClass('google', 16, 35)
```

And access values like:

```
print your_dictionary['google'].query, your_dictionary['google'].query_num, your_dictionary['google'].adver_num
```

Comment: if match[0].strip():
     if not dict.has_key(match[0]):
        dict[match[0]] = log(0,count_result)  class log:
    def __init__(query_num, adver_num):
        self.query_num = query_num
        self.adver_num = adver_num it report error

Comment: TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: @liumilan Yes, I am sorry I left self out from the arguments, now it should work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Using `query` as the key you can simply use a tuple as the value for the dict:

```
d = {"google": (16, 35)}
```

You can even use a dictionary as the value:

```
d = {"google": {"query number": 16, "advertisement number": 35}}
```

Comment: Can you give some code about using tuple? Now i use dict,if match[0].strip():
     if not dict.has_key(match[0]):
        dict[match[0]] = 1
     else:
        dict[match[0]] +=1

Comment: I don't understand you. If you want to use tuples, take a look at the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

Answer (score -1):

You can save the query sets into one and the same list with itertools chain as following;

```
#Import itertools
from itertools import chain
# use itertools chain to store your querysets into a list/variable like "store" 
store = list(chain(query_num, advertisement_num))
```

Comment: This wouldn't work as `chain` works on iterables (which integers aren't) and don't see how it pertains to answering the OP anyway...

Comment: Jon, either query_num stands for an integer or a set, and as I've interpreted the question it's about how to combine or save two sets and not two integers in the same dict. I've used itertools chain  in many Django functions and it works fine in my functions but there are other methods, filtering for instance, if this method isn't preferable.